# Creating a FillArray macro in asm

Tags: assembly, macros, x86, masm, irvine32

I am creating a Fillarray macros that I want to call from the main. I do not get any errors compiling it but the programs stops executing after I receive the first input from the user. Here is my code. Please help

```
INCLUDE c:\Irvine\Irvine32.inc

;// .386
;// .model flat,stdcall
;// .stack 4096
ExitProcess proto,dwExitCode:dword

;-----------------------------------------------------
mFillArrray MACRO a, b, d
;
;-----------------------------------------------------

;   mov ecx, LENGTHOF array         ;place the length in ecx
;   mov esi, OFFSET array           ;place the offset in esi
;   mov ebx, TYPE array             ;place the type in ebx

LOCAL L1

pushad
mov ecx, a
mov esi, b
mov ebx, d

L1: 
    call ReadInt                    ; read integer into EAX
    mov [esi],eax                   ; store in array
    add esi,ebx                     ; next integer
    loop L1
    popad
ENDM

.data                               ;// write your data in this section
array DWORD 10 DUP(?)
a DWORD ?
b DWORD ?
d DWORD ?
str1 BYTE "Please enter into the array:",0dh,0ah,0
endl BYTE 0dh,0ah,0 

.code       ;// write your program here
main proc

    mov edx,offset str1             ;moves into edx registry intro string
    call WriteString                ;writes the message

    mFillArrray a, b, d

    mov edx,offset endl             ;moves into edx registry intro string
    call WriteString                ;writes the message

    invoke ExitProcess,0
main endp

end main
```

Comment: `ebx` should contain the *length* of the type, in bytes, not the type itself. Please consider choosing more descriptive variable names than `a`, `b`, and `d`.

Comment: Where do you fill the variables `a`, `b`, `d` with values?

Comment: If I change TYPE to BYTE I get error message saying macros instructions are not the same size

Comment: In the L1 in the FillArray macro I have the ReadInt which get the user to input the value for the array. The LENGTHOF and TYPE are incremented values. So sorry. I am pretty naive with asm

Comment: Right, because they aren't BYTEs. `a`, `b`, and `d` are DWORDs. Look at this code: `add esi,ebx`. That's supposed to increment the pointer in `esi` to point to the next element in the array. But since each element is a DWORD, it is 4 bytes long, so you need to add 4 bytes.

Comment: thank you all for your comments. I fixed the code and has to fill the variables. Also made them descriptive